# IBM WAS 9, MDB deployment fail the entire application

Tags: jms, websphere

We have an IBM WebSphere AS 9.0.0.7 and when we want to deploy an application containing an MDB - which listens to a remote WebShpere MQ server - while the MQ server is down, then WAS reports an error

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internalerror caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
```

and stops the deployment, i.e. application does not start. Which is a big problem as it is a critical hub for other operations. We want to force WAS to start the application and retry the JMS connection later. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found a solution here: [Configuring properties for the IBM MQ resource adapter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tmm_wmqra_propconfig.html)

Trick was to set startupRetryCount and startupRetryInterval. When the MQ server is not available, the app starts, however it is reported as "Partial start". All other parts of the application seems to be running just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting custom property **WAS_EndpointInitialState** property to `INACTIVE`, see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rmj_wmq_mp_custproperties.html) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tmm_customproperties_jmsr.html), and also may want to look through [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tdat_msgendpoint.html).